# How to tell the difference between typeof(int) == typeof(int?) in C#

Tags: c#

Why does C# set these equal?

```
typeof(int).GetType() == typeof(int?).GetType()
```

The problem occurs when writing expression trees where I cast the

```
List<int?> ids = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int?>>(filter.Value?.ToString());
var filterField = filter.PropertyName;
var method = ids.GetType().GetMethod("Contains");
return Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(ids), method, member);
```

generates this error

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' of method 'Boolean Contains(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])

Is there a way to check the type before sending to the expression tree?

I tried checking the types of `int` and `int?` and both return true for the following check:

```
bool isIntNull = type == typeof(int?).GetType();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does C# set these equal?

Because they ARE equal.

`typeof(int)` generates a `RuntimeType` instance by the compiler

`typeof(int?)` generates a *different* `RuntimeType` instance by the compiler

calling `GetType()` on any `RuntimeType` instance returns the type `System.RuntimeType`

I think you want

```
typeof(int) == typeof(int?)
```

and

```
bool isIntNull = type.Equals(typeof(int?));
```

Proof:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int));
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?));
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int).GetType());
Console.WriteLine(typeof(int?).GetType());
```

output:

```
System.Int32
System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
System.RuntimeType
System.RuntimeType
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof(X)` operator always returns a `Type` object representing the type `X`.  The `GetType()` method returns the runtime type of the object it is called on.  So if you have the expression `typeof(X).GetType()` the first part of the expression will always return a `Type` instance, and the second part of that expression will always return a `Type` object representing the type `Type`, no matter what `X` is.  You want to compare `typeof(int)` to `typeof(int?)`, which are different.

Answer (score 1):

I think, whats wrong with your expression tree is that the `member` variable is an `Expression` of type `int` instead of `int?`.
The code you posted didn't show where it is coming from, but I think the following would help you:

```
return Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(ids), method, Expression.Convert(member, typeof(int?)));
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for answers and trying everything here, found this.

```
bool isIntNull = member.Type.IsGenericType && member.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem extracting data of an unknown runtime datatype to a known datatype - I solved the problem this way.

```
public bool CompareDataType<T>(Type runtimedatatype)
{
    Type KT = typeof(T);

    return runtimedatatype.Equals(KT) || runtimedatatype.Equals(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(KT));
}

int? output = null;
object RunTimeData = (object)((int)0);
if (CompareDataType<int?>(RunTimeData.GetType()))
    output = (int?)RunTimeData;
```

Alternatively you can create an extension of Object (which is what I went with in the end)

```
public static class ObjectTypeIsEqual
{
    public static bool CompareDataType<T>(this object input)
    {
        Type ObjectType = input.GetType();
        Type CompareType = typeof(T);

        return ObjectType.Equals(CompareType) || ObjectType.Equals(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(CompareType));
    }
}

int? output = null;
object RunTimeData = (object)((int)0);
if (RunTimeData.CompareDataType<int?>())
    output = (int?)RunTimeData;
```